# ¿Cómo resolver el error "Unexpected token at offset 24" (Mailkit) en C#?

Tags: c#, email, smtp

Buen día amigos. Estoy tratando de enviar un correo utilizando Mailkit y Mimekit, capturo los errores en caso de que ocurra. Obtengo el mensaje del título y
en el encabezado tengo lo siguiente

> De:ejemplo@dominio.com.mx
> Para:destinatario-de@hotmail.com
> Copia a:
> destinatario-de@hotmail.com;copiadestinatario@dominio.com

> Con esa línea de código agrega el destinatario al cuerpo del correo

```
message.To.Add(MailboxAddress.Parse("Destinatario@dominio.com"));
```

Lo que me llama la atención, pero no estoy seguro es que este correo (destinatario-de@hotmail.com) siempre se había enviado correos pero con otra aplicación. En un principio pensé que el caracter (-) está causando este problema con mimekit, pero ya realicé una prueba con correos similares y no provoca el error. Ayuda Gracias a todos No veo que alguien haya presenciado algo similar.

Comment: Debes poner donde aparece el error, y dar más detallas del mismo

Comment: De acuerdo, ya agregué que me muestre también el StackTrace de la excepción cuando ocurra el error.
No se ha provocado ese error de nuevo, pero si me causa inquietud porque no sé a qué se debió.